# 質問ページのタグ追加に関するポップオーバーで、「タグ作成を依頼」のリンク先がメインサイトとメタサイトで異なる

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, メタ

質問ページのタグ追加に関するポップオーバーで、「コミュニティにタグの作成を依頼」のリンク先がメインサイトとメタサイトで異なります。メインサイトの場合には [ja.meta.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/) へのリンクとなっていますが、メタサイトでは [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) へのリンクとなっています。

以下はメタサイトでのポップオーバーのスクリーンショットです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: +1: https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12501 ←この string のようですがリンク先は翻訳に入っていないので、コミュニティ・マネージャーさんの助けが必要そうです。

Comment: 他の関連サイトでも同じ状態でしたので、MSE に要望として投稿しました。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345258

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSE に出した要望がモデレーター判断で「再現性なし」になっていたので改めて確認したところ、どのタイミングからかは分かりませんが、メタサイトからのリンクも自サイトを指すように修正？されたようです。

**2020/08/08 現在のリンク状況:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 私の環境でも修正されていることが確認できたため、問題が解決済みであるとして質問を解決済みにしました。ご対応いただきありがとうございました！